# What does the red square in vs code source control mean?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've noticed while looking over the differences in vs codes source control that there will be random red squares. I can see the red lines/blocks and green lines/blocks easy. But I have no clue what these red squares mean and I don't see them in the code. Anybody know what those are for?

Tried googling around and all I saw was people asking about the red debug dot which is different.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They indicate the *scroll position* of errors/warnings.

The lighter section on the right is a sort of scroll bar, and the whole vertical section there represents the whole document:

[image]

As you can see, in the currently highlighted section - which represents the current section of the code visible in the viewport - there is a red dot just a bit above the middle. This corresponds to the error visible just above the middle of the viewport - the red squiggle below the `(req, res, next) =>` part.

You can see another two red dots a bit below the currently highlighted section. That means that if you scroll down one page, the next page will show two errors.

And so on. I see 6 dots, which means that there are at least 6 lines in the whole document that VSCode has detected have errors on them. Scroll to them using the red squares to see what they are.

Comment: Oh I see the little red squiggle for the error. Thanks for pointing that out to me CertainPerformance. I'll mark this as resolved in just a bit, stack overflow has this question on a cool down for 5 minutes.